# Update State of Stack Navigator Screen from Drawer Menu in React Native

Tags: react-native, react-navigation, react-navigation-drawer

I have created a drawer navigation menu in react native app using react navigation and added few screen like Screen 1,2...etc .Now in my drawer menu i have the app icon and below that the drawer menu are present so now on press of this icon i need to re-render Screen 1.

```js
class CustomDrawer extends Component {
    constructor(props) {
        super(props);
    }

    onAppIconClicked() {
        //here update the state of Screen 1
    }

    render() {
        return (
            <SafeAreaView style={styles.drawercontainer}>
                <View style={styles.drawermenu}>
                    <TouchableOpacity
                        style={styles.drawericon}
                        onPress={this.onAppIconClicked.bind(this)}
                    >
                        <Image
                            source={require("./src/images/mainicon.png")}
                            style={{ height: height(15), width: width(17), borderRadius: height(15) / 2 }}
                            resizeMode="contain"
                        />
                    </TouchableOpacity>
                </View>
                {/* some drawer items component */}
            </SafeAreaView>
        )
    }
}

const DrawerNavigatorExample = createDrawerNavigator({
    // Drawer Optons and indexing
    Screen0: {
        //Title
        screen: Screen1,
        navigationOptions: ({ navigation }) => {
            return {
                drawerLabel: () => null,
            }
        }
    },
    contentComponent: CustomDrawer
})

export default createAppContainer(DrawerNavigatorExample);
```

[image]